# How to display/execute PHP from an external file?

Tags: php

I have 2 files.

`test.zt` with the content of a lot of PHP and HTML come.

`index.php` where I'm including `test.zt` to display it's contents.

---

What I want to do now is to load `test.zt` contents into a variable (or something to be able to temporarily edit it). When it's done I want to use `str_replace()` function to change some text in the `test.zt` file temporarily. **I do not want to overwrite the original `test.zt` source file.**

After that I would like to display the changed file's content to the visitor.

**Note:** the code is containing PHP code and the page needs to execute that PHP code as well.

I have already tried to open the file with `file_get_contents()` and then echo out the contents, but it did not execute the PHP side of the content.

Is there any possibility to make this happen?

Comment: the horror! you can try to parse out the php and wrap it in an exec() function but that's like asking to explode. Do you have any code to represent what you've done so far?

Comment: Basically, you are asking for what `eval` does. And before you use that, please do some research on what downsides that has. // Instead of using `str_replace` to “change some text”, you should probably rather just include a normal PHP file, and have that use _variables_ from the main script to output parts of content that need to be dynamic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [type php code into textarea, store in database, then execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834463/type-php-code-into-textarea-store-in-database-then-execute)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318961/contents-of-a-file-get-content-to-process-php

Comment: From what I remember from my PHP days, eval was a pain in the ass.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the answer mate. I'm going to use variables then, it might be the best and safest version for me. You can create an answer copying the above content and I'll accept it. Thankd for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are asking for what `eval` does. But before you use that, please do some research on what downsides that has.

Instead of using `str_replace` to “change some text”, you should probably rather just include a normal PHP file, and have that use *variables* from the main script to output parts of content that need to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

When running the page take test.tz contents, alter it, write it to disk in a temp file, and include that temp file and then delete it. Or you could just leave it and keep overwriting it as long as it doesn't contain anything important.

Your question is so vague though it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you can write and then include a file in the same call. Have you tried to do this before?

Comment: No, but I don't see why you couldn't. The function returns when complete, and won't go to the next line until then. What does PHP care if the file is 1 second old or 30 seconds old. I do more ColdFusion now, but I have a page where it checks if a txt file exists, and if not, creates it and then reads it. Not sure PHP would be different. Unless the processor checks for includes lower on the page before running, shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That's now how PHP works, tho. It compiles first and then executes. Unless you know something I don't, that compile process would exclude you from doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried php [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function ?

```
$data = file_get_contents('test.zt');
eval($data);
```

**Note:**

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for this:

```
ob_start();
include "test.zt";
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo str_replace("some", "text", $contents);
```

Here is the PHP manual entry:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: no he wants to execute the content not just output it :)

Comment: Isn't that achieved by the include though? He stated that a get_file_contents wasn't working because "the php wasn't being executed".

Comment: Also the proposed solution also fits with the requirement of being able to replace text before it is outputted. Please explain how is this an inadequate answer. All other current proposed answers either suggest eval or suggest writing files on the file system.

Comment: i am sorry your answer seems legit after all.